# How to avoid image stretching in imageview

Tags: android

I have a image with 320x480 and i am running the application in device with 320x480. I set Image as `android:background` then my image is stretched. but if i use `android:src` then i am getting white space behind the image as if the image didnot cover the screen. How to set image in image view so that my image will neither be stretched and it will cover the whole screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/about1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: donot hide the reason behind downvoting if you are. which will help others to know the reason of downvoting

Comment: Please rephrase the last part of your question. Try to use bullet points to clearly state how the final image should behave

Comment: u need answer or reason for down vote?

Comment: @Raghu, I need answer as well as reason of downvoting. reason of downvote will help me to know my limitations while answer will help me get out of issue

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ImageView property [adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds).

Setting that to true has helped me in similar situations

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the image as the background of the LinearLayout?
If you do want to use the ImageView you should specify 'fill_parent' for the layout_height and layout_width.

Comment: i donot want image to be stretched

Answer (score 0):

You have to give height and width of image like you have image of 320*480 you have mention this size in xml while declaring the image and store the image in (drawable-mdpi)folder and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepakkk

i think you have stored image in drawable in hdpi or ldpi which are for high desity or low density

for emulator of size 320 * 480 you should store your source image in mdpi
[image]

change height of image to fill parent

try this

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <supports-screens
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
        ...
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I have done  the same. But this logic fails if i test my application in Motorolla milestone. It takes image from mdpi. But Its screen size is 480x854

Comment: are you using image for a tablet